# Visual Studio 2015 not building when I click start?

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2015

Having a weird issue with Visual studio refusing to build the project when I click start. I have changed many settings including "always build on run" setting. No dice.

Edit: I should clarify it does run the code but it's running an old version of it. It will not build with any changes I add.

Here's what I think screwed it up:
I was testing clock manipulation on a licensing system by changing the date on my computer forward. I think altering my date may have screwed up visual studios ability to detect whether the build is out of date somehow? Date and time are set back to normal and I have restarted my computer but still nothing. Any Ideas on how to get it to function properly again?

Comment: Are you sure there isn't just a build error?

Comment: Absolutely positive. I made a ton of changes to the code to test and it's running and old version of the build without those changes. I even updated the version and it still shows it as an old version.

Comment: I should have clarified it a bit better. It does build, just uses an old version.

Comment: If its using an "old" version that tells me its not actually doing a full build.  I routinely test code to change the clock, your problems, are something simple.  When you hit run, does it attempt to build, or just run?

Comment: I deleted the debug folder to test this out and still builds the old version. Makes no sense. Is there a cache of the data someplace?

Comment: Which mode are you currently set to, Debug or Release, been using Visual Studio for 17 years.  There is something simply...you are missing.  When you delete both the Release and Debug folder, does the project build, when you attempt to run it?  Have you verified the error window, is empty, seriously check.